# Slow SELECT examining whole table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Can you please help me to understand, why this select examines 828004 rows (whole database) to return 21 rows?

```
# Time: 161121 14:00:44
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.507397  Lock_time: 0.000089 Rows_sent: 21  Rows_examined: 828004
SET timestamp=1479733244;
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch)) AS NodeDate, DeviceID as NodeID, Description, 
AVG(AD0) AS AverageAD0,AVG(AD1) AS AverageAD1 
FROM Data 
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch)) >= CURDATE() 
AND HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch)) >= HOUR(current_time()) 
GROUP BY NodeDate, NodeID 
ORDER BY AVG(AD0) DESC, AVG(AD0) DESC;
```

#### Data table structure

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Data;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id          | int(10)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Epoch       | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Address     | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DeviceID    | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Description | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AD0         | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AD1         | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AD2         | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AnalogZero  | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Lat         | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Lon         | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| RSSI        | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Explain

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Data  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 822772 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

#### Indexes

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM Data;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Data  |          1 | Id       |            1 | Id          | A         |      839767 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The select is used to obtain averages from *today* AND current hour+.

This query is also examining all rows and looks super-simple. I have a 2-Core VPS and that is not handling such simple queries.

```
SELECT AVG(AD1) AS AverageAD1,AVG(AD2) AS AverageAD2, AVG(AD0) AS AverageAD0
FROM Data 
WHERE DeviceID="xxxxxxxx" 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE;
```

Comment: 'cos it's doing an aggregation. Post your `CREATE TABLE` statement along with an `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Are you sure that the `AND` is needed? Now you get only the information after the dates after (or on) `curdate()` and on these dates only after `HOUR(current_time())`.

Comment: Typo?  `ORDER BY AVG(AD0) DESC, AVG(AD0) DESC;` -- same thing twice?

Answer (score 2):

You want information based information that is in the `Epoch` field. Not even the whole field but just on `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch))` and `HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch))`. Unless you have an index on that information the database will always need to read every row of the table to see if the row fits the criteria.

Adding an index on `Epoch` as a whole will not help too. The `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch))` can be bypassed with (if it exists) `TO_UNIXTIME(CURDATE())` but the `HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch))` needs a specific index.

Comment: The select is used to obtain averages from TODAY AND current hour+


This QUERY is also examining all rows and looks super-simple.
I have a 2Core VPS and that is not handling such simple queries...


SELECT AVG(AD1) AS AverageAD1,AVG(AD2) AS AverageAD2, AVG(AD0) AS AverageAD0 FROM Data WHERE DeviceID="xxxxxxxx" AND FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE;

Answer (score 1):

Do not hide a column inside a function if you need to index it:

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch)) >= CURDATE() 
  AND HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Epoch)) >= HOUR(current_time())
```

Rewrite as

```
WHERE Epoch >= some-expression
```

and add `INDEX(Epoch)`.

Assuming you are truncating to the start of the current hour, let's try something:

```
SELECT NOW(), LEFT(NOW(), 13)
```

I get

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| NOW()               | LEFT(NOW(), 13) |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2016-11-21 15:37:13 | 2016-11-21 15   |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

With luck, I don't need to play any more games:

```
WHERE Epoch >= LEFT(NOW(), 13)
```

If that does not work, the try

```
WHERE Epoch >= CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 13), ':00:00')
```

Comment: WHERE Epoch >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 13), ':00:00')) will be 100% correct form

Comment: `CURDATE() + INTERVAL HOUR(NOW()) HOUR` might be a better approach than messing up with strings.